# Android - trouble loading ad using admob with adRquest

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, adview

I'm having some trouble incorporating ads to my app. I'm getting the following error: The constructor AdRequest(). On the line: adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

Here is the xml file I'm using containing the ad view:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RelativeLayout tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" 
    tools:context="com.example.blueshift.MainActivity" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/container" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

<com.example.blueshift.CustomView android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/custom_view"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/textView1" 
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
         android:text="djknfjndj" android:layout_marginBottom="128dp" 
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
     android:text="djknfjndj" android:layout_marginBottom="160dp" 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 

    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:text="Play Again" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
     android:visibility="gone" 
     android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"
                           ads:adUnitId="id"
                           ads:loadAdsOnCreate="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blueshift"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <activity

            android:name="com.example.blueshift.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the java code I'm using to try and load the add containing the error:

```
 AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

Followed Kishan's advice and implemented his changes, however now I'm getting the error The method loadAd(AdRequest) is undefined for the type AdView on the line adView.loadAd(adRequest); Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You havent add Adrequest so you are no getting use this:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
.build();

// Start loading the ad in the background.
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

For further details about load ad use this [Link.](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but now getting this error: The method loadAd(AdRequest) is undefined for the type AdView

Answer (score 0):

About the error msg:

> The method loadAd(AdRequest) is undefined for the type AdView on the
>   line adView.loadAd(adRequest);

The problems seems to be that you have set the wrong xml namespace:

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

this refers to the legacy Admob and you want to use the new admob, so use instead:

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

---

You may also check the import of AdView in your Activity code, it needs to be the following:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

---

Also remove this attribute from the AdView in the xml:

```
 ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
```

because that was only available for legacy Admob and you are already loading the ad programmatically.

For more infos about see this guide: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner